# Install screen on ubuntu 13.04 through .deb from web

Tags: gnu-screen, ubuntu-13.04, deb

I have a server on Rackspace w/ Ubuntu 13.04 (raring) that no longer has access to install packages through `apt-get`.

```
Err http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ raring/main screen amd64 4.0.3-14ubuntu9
  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/screen/screen_4.0.3-14ubuntu9_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I know I should be able to download a `.deb` from the web with `sudo dpkg -i DEB_PACKAGE`, but I'm struggling to find the package, (my google-foo is failing me). Can you point me to the appropriate download page for the screen package, compatible w/ Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 13.04 is no longer officially supported or maintained.  I very strongly suggest that you begin planning an upgrade to a supported release.  That system is going to be missing several critical unless you have been locally backporting patches.

If you really need this now as a short term fix while you start planning to upgrade your server ASAP, then you can update your apt sources to point at the old-releases archives.

- http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/